# c++ two functions do the same except one line

Tags: c++, templates, duplicates

I dont want to duplicate my code, but I have 2 functions which do the same except 1 line.
I do want separate functions that will call a private function, that might be a template and will solve my duplicate code problem.

```
double EuclideanDistance::calculateDistance(const Point &p1, const Point &p2) const
{
    if (p1.getDimension()!=p2.getDimension())
        return 0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < p1.getDimension(); i++)
    {
        sum += pow( p1[i] - p2[i], 2.0);
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}

double EuclideanDistance::calculateWeightedDistance(const Point &p1, const Point &p2, const double *weights) const
{
    if (p1.getDimension()!=p2.getDimension())
        return 0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < p1.getDimension(); i++)
    {
        sum += pow( ((p1[i] - p2[i])*weights[i]), 2.0);//here is the difference
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}
```

what do you suggest?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Any attempt to consolidate will reduce performance of the first version.

Comment: This belongs more on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). As an idea: The functions do the same if `weights` are all `1`. You can probably find a way to make that happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That's not the *only* line that differs. One of the functions takes different arguments as well, which makes this code just fine as two functions.

Comment: Both are one-liners and without `for` loops if you use `std::accumulate`

Comment: Using `pow` just to raise a double to the power of 2 is a bit overkill, IMO. `val = <expression>; val *= val;` would have far less overhead.

Comment: The rule is *not* to get rid of all code duplication at any cost - it is just a rule of thumb to avoid unnecessary duplication. Here you could cheat and rename the parameters `pA` and `pB` in one function, and magically there is no duplication. Or is there?

Answer (score 5):

Implement only `calculateWeightedDistance` fully.
and for `calculateDistance` call `calculateWeightedDistance` with weight `1.0`

Comment: Drawback is one needs to prepare the array filled with 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following?
If you invoke the function with the third parameter `nullptr`, then the behaviour of the first version is executed.

```
double EuclideanDistance::calculateWeightedDistance(const Point& p1, const Point& p2, const double* weights) const {
    if (p1.getDimension()!=p2.getDimension())
        return 0;

    double sum = 0.0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < p1.getDimension(); i++)
    {
        const auto distance_d = (p1[i] - p2[i]) * 
                                (weights != nullptr ? weights[i] : 1.0);
        sum += pow(distance_d, 2.0);
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be OpenCV. So I consider a massive amount of calculation could be possible. Branching in each iteration is not a neat idea in scope of potential optimisation.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Since the branch it's ways the same, likely branch prediction will hide the branch's cost

Comment: Very depends either on compiler implementation and architecture. I've just checked it on ARM (g++ -O2 flag), the condition is checked at every loop iteration. At least on ARM there is no branching in this moment, as it has conditional operations, so, the seqence is: `cmp r3, #0`; `ldrne r7, [r3, r4]`; `moveq r7, #1`. On Intel I must refresh my assembler knowledge, maybe later in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

You may factorize this way:

```
template <typename F, typename Ts...>
double calculateDistanceImpl(F&& f, const Point &p1, const Point &p2, Ts&&... args)
{
    if (p1.getDimension()!=p2.getDimension())
        return 0;

    double sum = 0.0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i != p1.getDimension(); i++)
    {
        sum += f(p1[i], p2[i], args[i]...);
    }
    return sqrt(sum);
}


double EuclideanDistance::calculateDistance(const Point &p1, const Point &p2) const
{
    return calculateDistanceImpl(
        [](auto&& p1, auto&& p2){ return pow(p1 - p2, 2.0);},
        p1, p2);
}

double EuclideanDistance::calculateWeightedDistance(const Point &p1,
                                                    const Point &p2,
                                                    const double *weights) const
{
    return calculateDistanceImpl(
        [](auto&& p1, auto&& p2, double weight){ return pow((p1 - p2) * weight, 2);},
        p1, p2, weights);
}
```